# M2 Show custom customer select attribut in frontend registration form

Tags: magento2, customer-account, forms, customer-attribute, registration

I have a custom customer select attribute and want to include it in my customer registration form on the frontend. Can anybody help with the **frontend part**? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by following these steps

let's say your attribute code is [**custom_att**]

in your module add this file to the **layout** folder

> app/code/{your-vendor}/{your-module}/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

in this file [**customer_account_create.xml**], add this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer1">
                <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">{your-vendor}_{your-module}::additional_customer_attribute.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            </block> 
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

in your module templates add this file

> app/code/{your-vendor}/{your-module}/view/frontend/templates/additional_customer_attribute.phtml

the code in this file is  [**additional_customer_attribute.phtml**]

```
<div class="field custom_att">
    <label for="custom_att" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Att') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <select id="custom_att" name="custom_att" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Custom Att') ?>" class="validate-select">
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">Option2</option>
        <option value="3">Option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can modify the options are you need

after this execute these two commands in magento root

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. Maybe that'll help you. I have found this solution from [Link](https://coolblueweb.com/blog/adding-a-customer-attribute-programmatically-in-magento-2/#).

```
<?php

namespace CoolBlueWeb\Example\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $_eavSetupFactory;
    private $_attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
    )
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function install( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context )
    {

        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        // add customer_attribute to customer
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_attribute');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_attribute', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Attribute',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'system' => 0,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'sort_order' => '200'
        ]
    );

    // allow customer_attribute attribute to be saved in the specific areas
    $attribute = $this->_attributeRepository->get('customer', 'customer_attribute');
    $setup->getConnection()
    ->insertOnDuplicate(
        $setup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
        [
            ['form_code' => 'adminhtml_customer', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
            ['form_code' => 'customer_account_create', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
            ['form_code' => 'customer_account_edit', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

Check `['form_code' => 'customer_account_create', 'attribute_id' => $attribute->getId()],` in above code.

I hope it'll help you.